# Persisting quartz job result

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to be able to persist a job result while a job is currently executing. I noticed @PersistJobDataAfterExecution which persists data to the job data map after a job finishes execution. However in my case I am looking to be able to persist some job related data while the job is executing.

As an example if I am using a job to upload some file to AWS s3 and I want to persist the progress, where should I be persisting that progress if I am only able to persist after job execution.

Comment: Where do you persist all the other data in your app?

Comment: In a postgres database. I think your answer might be implying that this is something that is outside of the scope of quartz and that I should be saving the job result somewhere else?

Comment: If you want to use that data anywhere outside of your job (which is what it looks like), then yes.

Comment: Yeah what I want is to show the progress of the job on a frontend UI to indicate how much of the upload is completed.

Comment: That's what I thought. Saving the progress to DB is probably the easiest option.